# Azure Pipelines: Notification on Job failure

Tags: .net, email, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

Is it possible to send a e-mail notification if a specific job fails within an azure pipeline?

Basically, i a testing stage in my pipeline where several jobs run in parallel which execute different test suites. Each test suite has a different guy who is responsible and must be notified if it fails.

I could only find notification options on failing the whole pipeline, but that's not what I want to do.

I also don't create any work items at the moment, and I couldn't find a "send-email-task" or something like this.

I could of course write my own script and execute it if a job fails, but I want to know if there is an easier way to solve my problem.

Comment: Tobias did you solved that issue ..? could you please post your solution here. thanks GJ

Comment: @GauravJoshi: Yes, I wrote a small powershell script to send an email after the job failed. See the last comment on this thread.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there is an out-of-the-box option like this, but you can use [Send Email](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.SendEmailTask) extension:

```
- task: SendEmail@1
  displayName: 'Send an email with subject Job A failed!'
  inputs:
    To: 'user@test.com'
    From: 'test@test.com'
    Subject: 'Job A failed!'
    SmtpServer: 'my smtp server'
  condition: failed()
```

Answer (score 3):

Since there is no build-in way to do this, I decided to add a small Powershell script which simply executes after the VSTest task in my testing stage. Also thanks to the *failed()* condition, it will only execute if at least one test failed.

Comment: So did you used custom email like Send-MailMessage -To “<recipient’s email address>” 
-From “<sender’s email address>”  
-Subject “Your message subject”
-Body “Some important plain text!” 
-Credential (Get-Credential) 
-SmtpServer “<smtp server>” -Port 587       I'm not sure if SMTP server will work with Devops or not. I want to implement with my azure devops release pipeline.

Comment: yes thats what I did. There was no other way for me. I used a google account.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write some external monitopring which will, verify status of your release throu REST API. I did something like this with proper azure function.

Comment: Rob can you please help me with how you implement Rest API for notification..? Thanks Gaurav

Comment: Please check links:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1

Here GET method is described for pipelines:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1

Also you can manually trigger new custom event which will be send to proper application insight:
https://microsoft.github.io/ApplicationInsights-Python/